# Generate UUID on kotlin-multiplatform?

Tags: kotlin, uuid, kotlin-multiplatform

Are there any kotlin-multiplatform common functions to get a UUID/GUID?

```
 // ideally something like this
 val newUUID = UUID() // "1598044e-5259-11e9-8647-d663bd873d93"
 println("newUUID = $newUUID")
```

I'd prefer not to make separate Android and iOS versions using expect-actual.

Comment: Does `UUID.randomUUID()` not work on iOS?

Comment: Are you certain Kotlin has a UUID type? I'm looking for something similar and I don't see the type at all.

Comment: UUID.randomUUID() seems to be a java function and is not available in MP: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/util/UUID#randomuuid

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As per the [Kotlin multiplatform documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-connect-to-apis.html#generate-a-uuid), you can make an `expect/actual` function to use the Android (java) and iOS (NSUUID) specific implementations:

```
// Common
expect fun randomUUID(): String
```

```
// Android
import java.util.UUID

actual fun randomUUID() = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
```

```
// iOS
import platform.Foundation.NSUUID

actual fun randomUUID(): String = NSUUID().UUIDString()
```

Answer (score 10):

That one may work
https://github.com/benasher44/uuid

The sources of the project use the Kotlin Multiplatform project to implement the UUID library. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html for more details

Answer (score 1):

Using SHA-1 from: https://github.com/KotlinCrypto/hash

For a custom `UUIDv5` implementation I tried something like this:

```
import org.kotlincrypto.hash.sha1.SHA1

class UUID(
    val string: String
) {

    @OptIn(ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)
    fun generateUUID5(namespaceUuid: String, inputObject: Any): UUID {
        val objectString = inputObject.toString()
        val sha1Bytes = SHA1().digest((namespaceUuid + objectString).toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))
        val uuidBytes = sha1Bytes.copyOfRange(0, 16)

        uuidBytes[6] = (uuidBytes[6].toInt() and 0x0f or 0x50).toByte()
        uuidBytes[8] = (uuidBytes[8].toInt() and 0x3f or 0x80).toByte()

        val hexUuidString = uuidBytes.toHexString()

        val formattedAsUUID = hexUuidString.replaceFirst(Regex("^(.{8})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{12})$"), "$1-$2-$3-$4-$5")

        return UUID(formattedAsUUID)
    }

}
```

The `toHexString()` function uses the `ExperimentalStdlibApi`.

Should work fine with multiplatform.